# How can i insert the values of text boxes and their id into mysql from an html page using jquery through netbeans

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, netbeans-7

How can i insert the values of text boxes and their id into mysql from an html page using jquery through netbeans on submit

sample code of html is given below..
please help me with the code

```
<tr rowspan=3 colspan=3>
   <td class="tdright"><input type="text" id="1.3_1_1" name="1.3_1_1" title="qry"></td>
  <td class="tdright"><input type="text" id="1.3_1_2" name="1.3_1_2" title="qry"></td>
  <td class="tdright"><input type="text" id="1.3_1_3" name="1.3_1_3" title="qry"></td>
  <td class="tdright"><input type="text" id="1.3_1_4" name="1.3_1_4" title="qry"></td>
  <td class="tdright"><input type="text" id="1.3_1_5" name="1.3_1_5" title="qry"></td>
  <td><input type="text" id="1.3_1_6" name="1.3_1_6" title="qry"/></td>
 </tr>
```

Comment: Our role is not to develop stuff for you. You need to search and try by yourself. Google around, make some attempts. We are here to help people whose code should work, but doesn't. You have no code at all.

Comment: It's not a reply. It's what we say to all newbies who come here for us to do their homework.

Comment: if i get a solution for this row i can apply this to my entire code.....thats why am asking help

Comment: Yes, just ask Google : "how to insert values from a HTML form into MySQL" and you will have millions of tutorials, videos, blogs telling you how to do this and where to start. If you just come here and ask, "Hey guys, do this for me", it looks like you're too lazy to try yourself and you don't want to learn. You just want other people to tell you how to do without searching, just like Muhammad did below. You could have found this answer in 20 seconds on google.

Comment: Don't take it bad. It's for your own good =)